# ConversationState in Microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, azure-cosmosdb, chatbot

I am using the proactive messaging sample of Bot Framework from [BotBuilderSamples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages)

For proactive messaging, idea to store the userID/conversationRef for all my users and then via the Notify Controller loop over it and send proactive messages

I have already setup cosmosdb to store the conversationid via ConversationState object.

My questions is, can i use the same conversationState object to store the conversationReferences of all my users? OR do i need to store this array of conversationReferences in a separate partion and load it manually.

I think the question ultimately boils down to this... the conversationState object in BotFramework is Universal to all users or is it specific to per user?
The documentation is not explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

> My questions is, can i use the same conversationState object to store
> the conversationReferences of all my users? OR do i need to store this
> array of conversationReferences in a separate partion and load it
> manually.

The conversationState object is going to be unique per conversation. So, you don't need to do anything special. Conversations can have multiple users of course, so; you can use Private Conversation State if you really need to.

Per documentation:
"*The keys used for each of these predefined buckets are specific to the user and conversation, or both. When setting the value of your state property, the key is defined for you internally, with information contained on the turn context to ensure that each user or conversation gets placed in the correct bucket and property.*"

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#state-management